# Retrieve Office 365 Planner Tasks using CSOM C# or powershell

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom, tasks

How to retrieve **Office365 Planner** Plans, Tasks and Buckets in console application using CSOM C# or using Powershell ?

Answer (score 4):

As it stands now, you can't use CSOM to access Planner, but you can use the Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Comment: How to use Graph API in my console application ?

Comment: That is a very loaded question, go to the dev site, see link above, and start there.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is currently in beta in the Office Graph. See [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/task_get) for documentation on retrieving tasks. For other capabilities, see the left nav on that page, scroll down to the beta section, and there's a category for "planner tasks", as well as "plans".

Comment: How to use Graph API in my console application ?